# Pandas Error - Attempting to convert column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas column with datetime.

```
df['Date']
0     2021-11-23 00:00:00
1     1998-09-10 00:00:00
2     2003-07-07 00:00:00
3     2021-09-30 00:00:00
4     1998-12-01 00:00:00
                    ...            
10    2012-07-17 18:53:11.768209
11    2012-07-17 18:53:11.768209
```

when I attempt to run `to_datetime` like this, I run into an error.

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

I need `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

Running `.describe()` on the column gives;

```
count                          12644
unique                          2868
top       2012-07-17 18:53:11.768209
freq                            7614
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Traceback:

```
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'float'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/d0/gnksqzwn2fn46fjgrkp6045c0000gn/T/ipykernel_50443/2864776076.py in <module>
      7 
      8 
----> 9 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
     

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
   1045                 result = arg.tz_localize(tz)
   1046     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
-> 1047         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
   1048         if not cache_array.empty:
   1049             result = arg.map(cache_array)

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    195         unique_dates = unique(arg)
    196         if len(unique_dates) < len(arg):
--> 197             cache_dates = convert_listlike(unique_dates, format)
    198             cache_array = Series(cache_dates, index=unique_dates)
    199             # GH#39882 and GH#35888 in case of None and NaT we get duplicates

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    400     assert format is None or infer_datetime_format
    401     utc = tz == "utc"
--> 402     result, tz_parsed = objects_to_datetime64ns(
    403         arg,
    404         dayfirst=dayfirst,

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object, allow_mixed)
   2240             return values.view("i8"), tz_parsed
   2241         except (ValueError, TypeError):
-> 2242             raise err
   2243 
   2244     if tz_parsed is not None:

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object, allow_mixed)
   2222     order: Literal["F", "C"] = "F" if flags.f_contiguous else "C"
   2223     try:
-> 2224         result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(
   2225             data.ravel("K"),
   2226             errors=errors,

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array
```

Comment: Do you need just the date or do you need the hours, mins, ect as well?

Comment: I need `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: Can you give us a describe() of the column?

Comment: @keynesiancross Added the output of `describe()` to the post.

Comment: you may have `nan` in your column, pass `errors='coerce'`?

Comment: My guess without seeing all the data is a nan in there.  Try a dropna and see if it works as a test

Answer (score 1):

If you only need up to the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` values you can use this to turn the column into a datetime value

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.split('.')[0]))
```